# How do I add gmail account to Windows 8 mail app, when it won't let me

Tags: windows-8, email

I've tried to add my gmail account to the Windows 8 mail app, but I keep getting a message saying the information I entered may not be correct. I have gone to gmail.com and am 100% sure that I am entering the correct email address and current password. How can I get this to work for me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these tutorials:

- [How to Add and Configure Gmail in Windows 8 Mail App](http://www.guidingtech.com/14256/add-configure-gmail-windows-8-mail-app/)
- [How to Add Gmail in Windows 8 Mail App](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/add-gmail-to-windows-8-mail/)
- [Video: Add Gmail Account in Windows 8 Mail App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erGJrLi4EDg)
- [CNET How To How to add Gmailaccounts in Windows 8 Mail](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57550106-285/how-to-add-gmail-and-yahoo-accounts-in-windows-8-mail/)
- [Can't add gmail account in Windows 8 Mail app](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-ecoms/cant-add-gmail-account-in-windows-8-mail-app/97e190b5-55a7-4398-ae44-daddec1ee8ed)

> When you add the account are you checking the sync contacts and
>   calendar setting in the add account experience? If not can you try
>   with the option selected ? With the sync calendar and contacts
>   settings unchecked mail tries to add the account as an imap account,
>   if that's how you would like to sync your Google account you'll need
>   to check if imap is enabled for your account on the email account
>   settings page on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already add a Microsoft account? You have to do that first, then you can add a Gmail account in the app settings.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ZDNet](http://www.zdnet.com/gmail-loses-google-sync-how-windows-8-rt-office-are-affected-7000008846/), it is not possible any longer since January 30th because Google *dropped support for Google Sync for customers who use its free Gmail and Google Apps services*.

You should be able to use IMAP though.